# Why grails run-app tries to access remote servers during compiling

Tags: grails

I found there are some errors during my grails application compiling.

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.4
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server 
url=http://plugins.grails.org/grails-shiro/tags/RELEASE_1_2_0-SNAPSHOT/shiro-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

But I can access the above url using my browser. What does the error mean? and is there any way to avoid such problems during compiling? Or can I compile my grails app locally?

when I need some grails plugin, I usually run
    grails install-plugin xxx 
to install xxx plugins. I noticed that there are some records automatically written in 'application.properties'. And the plugins are always installed in my ~/.grails//projects/plugins/, I am wondering whether there are ways to compile grails app locally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a `SNAPSHOT` plugin, that means that Grails have to refresh this plugin periodically (once a day).

To disable remote repositories you can use `--offline` to work offline:

```
grails --offline run-app
```

Or disable it completelly by adding into `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.offline.mode=true
```

See docs for Dependecy Resoultion - https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.0.4/guide/conf.html#dependencyRepositories

P.S. Latest stable version of [Shiro plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro) is `1.1.4`, you could also use it instead of `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`. Stable version will be downloaded only once.