# Grails command (create-app test), updating grails dependencies for project test

Tags: java, grails, ggts

I am a new Grails user. I downloaded Grails 2.4.4 + SBT. I believe have
installed it correctly and, when I try to run a test application, I get the following message (error):

```
The command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javaw.exe (4 déc. 2014 16:12:47)' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time. See details for the output produced so far.
```

My Java and Grails paths are correctly configured.

So why I'm getting this error?

after adding proxy setting i got this error :

```
    Problem executing: grails add-proxy toto --host=192.168.1.1 --port=3128 
    The command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javaw.exe 
    was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.
    See details for the output produced so far.





If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the time           limit in  the Grails preferences page.



See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch
Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javaw.exe (8 déc. 2014 13:30:47)
---- System.out ----
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
---- System.err ----

Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 180000 milliseconds
------System.out:-----------
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
------System.err:-----------

Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 180000 milliseconds
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probabily is behind a proxy.
Check on the command line: `grails list-plugins`.
If it fails set your proxy configuration (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html):

```
grails add-proxy client --host=proxy-server --port=4300 
       --username=guest --password=guest
grails set-proxy client
```

Comment: thanks, it's possible to work with grails without internet connections ?

Comment: Grails needs to download all dependencies that you are using in your app (plugins, jars...). After the download you can use the offline mode, see here: [http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html)

Comment: See this answer for example: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470813/why-grails-run-app-tries-to-access-remote-servers-during-compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470813/why-grails-run-app-tries-to-access-remote-servers-during-compiling)

Comment: so, if i want to work offline, what i am suppose to do ? it's a bundle that i can download directly ?

Comment: Grails can use `maven` or `ivy` for dependency resolution. When you work with the offline mode, grails assumes that you have already downloaded all dependencies and their are in your local cache. I suggest you read about dependency resolution to understand better and see the docs: [http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution)